# Monitoring amino acid esterification

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, chromatography, amino-acids

I am trying to monitor the esterification of a non UV active amino acid.I used thionyl chloride and Methanol as reagents.

As amino group is unprotected, Ninhydrin should give positive result for both reactant and products. However, I believe there should be Rf difference between reactant and product.When I performed TLC and stained with ninhydrin, the reactant was strong brown and one spot at very high Rf value showed pale brown coloration.Now can I think that pale brown spot as my target ester?

I am doubtful because reactant and product both supposed to show strong coloration as amino group is not affected.On the other hand,  will just methylating the acid result in high Rf change? Because I feel amino group is also polar, it would not allow spot to raise till high Rf end.

Comment: On what medium did you perform TLC? Silica?

Comment: Yes Silica.CHCl3/MeOH

Comment: You could use a bromcresol green stain which is indicative of carboxylic acids, details here https://www.silicycle.com/faq/thin-layer-chromatography/stains-for-tlc-plates  Do you have access to alumina plates?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to Alumina plate. To add some more information the top spot is tailing. Is it due to free amine?

Comment: I doubt it is free amine, you normally need to add NH3 to your eluent to get free amine off the baseline. How much MeOH are you using in the eluent?

Comment: I add approx. 5:2 (Chloroform:MeOH).Actually I would like to know what usually causes tailing?Also, what is the role of ammonia?I wonder do esters tail?

Comment: That's a lot of MeOH! Maybe it is your ester.Try a KMNO4 visualisation.  Adding NH3 neutralises the acidic sites on the silica surface so that the basic amino group binds less and will elute up the plate.

Comment: @Waylander So do you think free amine in ester is the cause for tailing? On the other hand,if I use Ammonia during column, is there a risk of Amide formation? In other words,how can I avoid tailing of ester in silica column without allowing hydrolysis/side reactions?

Comment: Without NH3 or some other base in the eluent I think the tailing is due to free amine. I have routinely used Ammonia in Methanol/DCM as an eluent for basic species and never seen ester degradation. If it is a concern you could use triethylamine in place of ammonia.

Comment: @Waylander Thank you very much for your detailed explanation!